# Unorderable Types: int() < str()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get the error 'Unorderable Types: int() < str()' and I'm not sure why.

```
end = input('enter total numbers:')
int(end)
total = 0
float(total)
number = 0
float(number)

while number < end:
    add = input('enter number to add:')
    total = total + add
    number = number + 1

print (total / end)
```

Comment: If Martjin's answer helped, you should consider accepting it.

Answer (score 5):

`int(end)` *returns the new integer*, but you are ignoring it:

```
end = input('enter total numbers:')
int(end)
```

Assign the result back to `end`:

```
end = input('enter total numbers:')
end = int(end)
```

You made the same mistake with the `float()` calls, but here it won't lead to any errors. If `number` and `total` must be floating point numbers, just use floating point literals:

```
total = 0.0
number = 0.0
```

but when using the `/` operator it doesn't matter if `total` is a float or an int.

You need to also convert `add`:

```
add = input('enter number to add:')
add = int(add)
```

You can combine the `int()` calls with the `input()` calls:

```
end = int(input('enter total numbers:'))
```

and

```
add = int(input('enter number to add:'))
```

In any case, `float()` and `int()` are not *type declarations*; Python doesn't have any type declarations like a language like C or Java has. Variables are untyped; you can put anything in `end` or `total` or `number` and Python wouldn't blink an eyelid.

Instead, you use `int()` and `float()` to *convert* an object of a different type; like a string converted to an integer, or an integer to a floating point number, or a floating point number to an integer.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have to do that for float(total) or float(number) though?

Comment: @G3ck0: no, because it doesn't matter here if they are floats or integers. You *could* fix that there too, but you may as well just use. `total = 0.0` and `number = 0.0` instead.