# error TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, tf-idf, lda

I am getting this error

```
        Using Python version 3.5.2+ (default, Sep 22 2016 12:18:14)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/saria/PycharmProjects/TfidfLDA/main.py", line 30, in <module>
    corpus = indexed_data.select(col("KeyIndex",str).cast("long"), "features").map(list)
  File "/home/saria/tf27/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 956, in col
    return 1 if 0<loc<len(s) and s[loc-1] == '\n' else loc - s.rfind("\n", 0, loc)
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()

Process finished with exit code 1
```

when I am running the following code. I should explain that the error happen in this line:

```
corpus = indexed_data.select(col("KeyIndex",str).cast("long"), "features").map(list)
```

I reviewd these cases:

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29162854/unorderable-types-int-str)

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561397/python-error-typeerror-unorderable-types-list-int)

but they are about the conversion int and string, specially reading Input.
but here I dont have input,
**Explanations abt the code:**
this code is doing tfidf+lda using Dataframe

```
    # I used alias to avoid confusion with the mllib library
from pyparsing import col
from pyspark.ml.clustering import LDA
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF as MLHashingTF, Tokenizer, HashingTF, IDF, StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml.feature import IDF as MLIDF
from pyspark.python.pyspark.shell import sqlContext, sc

from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType, StructField, StringType, StructType
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row

dbURL = "hdfs://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music"
file = sc.textFile("1.txt")
#Define data frame schema
fields = [StructField('key',StringType(),False),StructField('content',StringType(),False)]
schema = StructType(fields)
#Data in format <key>,<listofwords>
file_temp = file.map(lambda l : l.split(","))
file_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(file_temp, schema)
#Extract TF-IDF From https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/ml-features.html
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol='content', outputCol='words')
wordsData = tokenizer.transform(file_df)
hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol='words',outputCol='rawFeatures',numFeatures=1000)
featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(wordsData)
idf = IDF(inputCol='rawFeatures',outputCol='features')
idfModel = idf.fit(featurizedData)
rescaled_data = idfModel.transform(featurizedData)
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol='key',outputCol='KeyIndex')
indexed_data = indexer.fit(rescaled_data).transform(rescaled_data).drop('key').drop('content').drop('words').drop('rawFeatures')
corpus = indexed_data.select(col("KeyIndex",str).cast("long"), "features").map(list)
model = LDA.train(corpus, k=2)
```

May please give me your idea,

when I delete the str in the error prone line:

```
corpus = indexed_data.select(col("KeyIndex",str).cast("long"), "features").map(list)
```

, It throws a new error
 `TypeError: col() missing 1 required positional argument: 'strg'`

**Update**
**My main goal is to run this code :**

[tfidf then lda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583702/from-tf-idf-to-lda-clustering-in-spark-pyspark)

Comment: It looks like `loc` is a string, not a number, hence the error. Did you try `print(repr(loc))` before the failing comparison? If yes, what did it show?

Comment: thanks for your answer @9000 but wat do u mean by LOC , I dont have LOC here!!!

Comment: @AnthonySottile excuse me , I didnt get you :(, do u mean the full error?

Comment: @AnthonySottile, sure I am going update the question

Comment: I update the question @AnthonySottile , thanks :)

Comment: @AnthonySottile may I ask you to look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583702/from-tf-idf-to-lda-clustering-in-spark-pyspark becaz I am trying to do the same, it does not have str as I explained above, but without str It raises errors as I explained above also, thanks for your time

Comment: @AnthonySottile I see, thanks any way, Is it clear now?

Comment: @9000 may I ask you to explain more, I am newbie to this field :(

Comment: I was looking at `if 0<loc<len(s)`, but now I realize it's not your code! It apparently belongs to `pyparsing` library, and can even be a bug in it.